# Erro ao colocar imagem em ImageButton

Tags: java, android

Quando havia somente uma pasta drawable este erro não estava acontecendo, só que o app ficava distorcido em outras resoluções, dai criei as pastas drawable com diferentes resoluções(ldpi, hdpi...) e dentro delas botei a imagem que quero setar com seu devido DPI em cada. A partir disto o aplicativo começou a quebrar na hora em que a imagem deveria ser setada. Se excluo as pastas drawable e deixo somente a padrão funciona.

```html
04-26 14:42:13.261    1467-1467/com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ 78925456-byte external allocation too large for this process.
04-26 14:42:13.280    1467-1469/com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4K, 50% free 2837K/5639K, external 2755K/3376K, paused 4ms
04-26 14:42:13.280    1467-1467/com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha E/GraphicsJNI﹕ VM won't let us allocate 78925456 bytes
04-26 14:42:13.280    1467-1467/com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha D/skia﹕ --- decoder->decode returned false
04-26 14:42:13.280    1467-1467/com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-26 14:42:13.280    1467-1467/com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3fe14f0)
04-26 14:42:13.280    1467-1467/com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:460)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
            at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7533)
            at com.app.gustavo.jogodavelha.Main.clickQuadrado(Main.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Poste o *log* do erro e o código que está a usar para "setar" a imagem.

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: Esta é a causa do erro: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`. que em termos simples quer dizer que a imagem é grande de mais, a memória é insuficiente para tratar essa imagem.

Comment: Ata, mas por que quando eu deixo apenas uma pasta drawable não aparece o erro?

Comment: Julgo que deve ser porque a imagem que está nessa pasta é mais pequena.

Comment: Pelo que entendi do log de erro, ao carregar a imagem houve uma alocação de 78MB. Uma sugestão que eu dou é implementar um algoritmo de cache usando o `LRUCache` e adicionar a imagem em uma resolução razoável, algo em torno de 800x600 e deixar que o `ImageView` faça escala usando o `scaleType` ou você mesmo ao carregar. Ah, uma outra sugestão é colocar a imagem na pasta `drawable-nodpi`.

Comment: Era realmente esse o problema obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Este erro trata-se de um vazamento de memória.

A sua aplicação está atribuída um tamanho de ~ 24MB. Mas as imagens que você está tentando setar talvez, eu digo talvez sejam, sejam do que o tamanho da pilha.

Isso está acontecendo porque você não está liberando a memória, fazendo com que o Android Dalvik VM não cuide do `GC`-ing, memória nativa usada pelo aplicativo. Quando se lida com imagens em Android, você precisa usar explicitamente `reciclagem()`. Isso libera a memória nativa.

Para mais deatils: [Changing ImageView content causes OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191407/changing-imageview-content-causes-outofmemoryerror)

Mas por desencargo de consciência, tente:

1. Executar um `clean`
2. Um `Rebuild`
3. `Invalid Caches/Restart`

Answer (score 1):

O erro acontece devido à pouca memória do emulador. Você pode acrescentar mais memória. Aconselho usar o genymotion, que mesmo em sua versão gratuita é muito útil para a maioria das aplicações.